# How to use the "clockwise/spiral rule" to read a const class member function?

Tags: c++

How to use the "[clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)" to read a const class member function? Like:

```cpp
class Box {
    // ...
    double volume() const;  // <= How to read this function?
}
```

Comment: Note the "clockwise/spiral rule" is from **c-faq**, not **c++faq**, so for declarations that do not have a C counterpart (like those with `const` at the end), you are not going to get a `1:1` application of the rule. How to read it? It is a function taking no arguments are returning `double` that is `const`.

Comment: Note the clockwise/spiral rule isn't very good to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite the spiral rule here, as that isn't a singular type definition, but a function instead:

```
 double volume() const;
  ^       ^       ^---- Operates on const instance of Box
  |       \--- Function name
  \-- Return type
```

Anything with a trailing `const` on it can operate on `const Box`, while absent that, you need a mutable version or you can't use it. You'll get some kind of compiler error saying it can't find a function for a `const Box` even though you'd suppose such a function is defined.

Often you'll see things like:

```
  const myType& getType() const;
```

Where that returns a `const` value from a `const` instance. These often end up paired, as in:

```
  const myType& getType() const;
  myType& getType();
```

Where the first one is for read-only access, and the second one allows alteration.

Comment: The trailing `const` declares that the method will not change any of the class's attributes.  That allows you to use a const instance, but it also indicates that nothing will be changed if the instance is non-const.

Comment: @Den-Jason Well, you promise not to, at least, but yeah `this` is treated as `const` within any calls to that.